# Unity3d - How to parent a worldspace GUI to a car?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, vector

How can I attach a worldspace UI onto my car object? I'm using the UI Image rotational fill for a speedometer, how would I attach this image to my car? I've made it work somewhat by setting the position and rotation to that of the car, but  it moves from it's position when turning, while still being rotated correctly. Help?
Code:

```
Vector3 basePos = relevantParent.transform.position;
Vector3 tweakedPos = basePos;
tweakedPos.x = tweakedPos.x + xOffset;
tweakedPos.y = tweakedPos.y + yOffset;
tweakedPos.z = tweakedPos.z + zOffset;
transform.position = tweakedPos;
transform.localRotation = relevantParent.transform.localRotation;
```

Comment: Couldn't you parent this in the hierarchy or are one of these object generated at runtime?

Comment: I tried parenting in the hierarchy, but that doesnt work. Doh09's answer worked for me though, oddly enough. Guess it has to be a manual parenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html

RectTransform, which a world space canvas has as to know its position, rotation and so on, inherits from Transform.

Transform can set its parent object.

So grab your RectTransform from the WorldSpace canvas and set it's parent to be your cars transform.

```
RectTransform rectTransform;
rectTransform.parent = transform; //transform of your car.
```